# Is there a way to loop through dynamically created componenets in java?

Tags: java, swing, dynamic

I am dynamically creating jtextfields and I was wondering if there was a way to loop through each one and check for it's value

something like this:

```
foreach(JTextField:jtf in JFrame)
    System.out.prinlnt(jtf.getText());
```

Edit:

The current way I'm doing this is creating an array list:

```
private ArrayList<JTextField> txtFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

When I call createDynamic:

```
final JTextField txtDirPath = new JTextField(20);
txtFields.add(txtDirPath);
```

Then on my button I have an action which perform this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < txtFields.size(); i++) {
    String strPath = txtFields.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(txtFields.size());
    System.out.println(strPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put you text fields in a list (`java.util.List<JTextField>`) when creating them dynamically, and loop over this list :

```
for (JTextField jtf : theListOfTextFields) {
    System.out.prinln(jtf.getText());
}
```

Comment: I try this but the list is not giving me the correct output, let me post some code.

Comment: Okay I have some success, Just now it prints the output twice instead of once. But it is getting the correct information.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Component c : jframe.getComponents()) {
    if (c instanceof JTextField)
        System.out.println(((JTextField)c).getText());
}
```

Comment: This will only return the direct children of the JFrame. JTextFields are typically put in the content pane of the JFrame, or in a sub panel of the content pane.

Comment: @JB Nizet you'r right, but it's not rocket science to add recursion :-) Seriously, I prefer the dynamic lookup over keeping a list somewhere - concededly a matte of taste

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store thos in a list as @JB Nizet proposed, You can call [`Container#getComponents`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponents%28%29) to get an array of all the child components. And for each one check if it a `JTextField`.

```
Component[] compArr = myFrame.getComponents();
for (Component comp : compArr) {
    if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
        System.out.prinlnt(((JTextField)comp).getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Component c : myJFrame.getComponents){
   if (c instanceof JTextField){
      // do work here
   }
}
```

Comment: This will only return the direct children of the JFrame. JTextFields are typically put in the content pane of the JFrame, or in a sub panel of the content pane.